# Error: string indices must be integers in Llama-2-13b

Tags: python, langchain, large-language-model, llama

Im new in llm and Im trying to combine llama with my documents in telegram, but got the Error: string indices must be integers
Here some code:

```
memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history", return_messages=True)

def create_chain(_retriever):
    qa_chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(llm, retriever=_retriever, memory=memory, verbose=False)
    return qa_chain

llm_chain = create_chain(db.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k":2}))

if stream and max_tokens > 2048:
    logger.warning("This is likely to exceed 4096 characters, which would not fit into one stream message")
    return llm_chain.run(prompt)

user_prompt = job[0]
chat_id = job[1]
msg = job[2]
custom_prompt = job[3]

try:
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=msg.chat.id, text="Started to generate text for you...",
                          message_id=msg.message_id)
    logger.info(f"Generating text for user {msg.chat.username}")

    if custom_prompt:
        json_obj = generate_text(user_prompt, chat_id=chat_id, stream=False,
                                 custom_prompt=True)
    else:
        json_obj = generate_text(user_prompt, chat_id=chat_id, stream=False)
    output = json_obj['choices'][0]["text"]

    logger.debug(json.dumps(json_obj, indent=2))
    text_to_user = output`
```

I suppose I should fix the json part somehow but I couldn't figure out how